# -[__NSDictionaryI rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` within a `UITableView` and when it's tapped and you start typing, it will auto-update the list. I have an NSMutableArray named `_cloudItems` which returns a JSON (I am using [JJCloudEngine](https://github.com/jnjosh/JJCloudEngine) to retrieve the JSON string).

Most of the code in the project is fine, expect this block of code that is giving me this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e343e0'`

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        // Set bollean flag
        isFiltered = NO;
    } else {
        // Set boolean flag
        isFiltered = YES;

        // Alloc and init our fliteredData
        filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Fast enumeration
        for (NSString *name in _cloudItems) {
            NSRange nameRange = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                [filteredList addObject:name];

            }
        }
    }
    // Reload tableView
    [table reloadData];

}
```

I am aware that these two lines of code are the cause of the problem:

```
for (NSString *name in _cloudItems) {
                if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
```

NOTE: `_cloudItems` is an `NSMutableArray` and gets it's code from this block of code:

```
- (void)itemsRecieved:(NSArray *)items forRequest:(NSString *)connectionId {

    NSLog(@"cloud engine recieved items on request %@", connectionId);
    _cloudItems = items;
    [table reloadData];

}
```

I have tried changing `for (NSString *name in _cloudItems) {` into `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` and they don't work. I have also added this:

```
NSDictionary *dictItem = [_cloudItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

for (NSString *name in dictItem) {
```

But this error message happens:

`Use of undeclared identifier 'indexPath'; did you mean 'NSIndexPath'?`

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where is `nameRange` coming from?

Comment: the object in _cloudItems is NSString or NSDictionary?

Comment: @Chancy Like I stated in the question, `_cloudItems` is a `NSMutableArray`. It is receiving its information from `- (void)itemsRecieved:(NSArray *)items forRequest:(NSString *)connectionId {`

Comment: NSDictionary *dictItem = [_cloudItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and for (NSString *name in _cloudItems) is quite different

Comment: @Wevah Interestingly enough, that was not copied over. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Chancy I realize that now, but it was just a desperate attempt to try anything to remedy this problem.

Comment: NSDictionary *dictItem = [_cloudItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; means object in _cloudItems is NSDictionary, while the latter means is NSString...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42080/discussion-between-chancy-and-junior117)

Comment: It sounds an awful lot like your cloudItems value is coming from a JSON payload, or something similar.  NSLog cloudItems and copy/paste the result (or a representative sample) into your question.  I'm betting it's much more complicated than a simple array of strings.

Comment: And how is _cloudItems actually declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
for (id name in _cloudItems) {
        if([name isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
            NSRange nameRange = [(NSString *)name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                [filteredList addObject:name];

            }
        }
    }
```

you should confirm the name is `NSString`, then use `rangOfString`.Some object in the array is `NSDictionary`. if all the objects are `NSDictionary` you maybe need something like followings:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in _cloudItems) {

    NSString *name = [item objectForKey:@"somekey"];
    NSRange nameRange = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        [filteredList addObject:name];

    }
}
```

Comment: @Junior117 it means all your object in the _cloudItems is NSDictionary

Comment: Is there a way to turn it into an `NSArray` while having each item in it's appropriate tableview cell?

Comment: @Junior117 you should know your NSArray structure then use it.check my updated answer. you should know something about the NSDictionary in your NSArray

Comment: Ok. It works now. Thank you and I very much appreciate all of the trouble that you had to go through.

Answer (score 1):

maybe one of your name in _clouditems is not [NSString], is [NSDictionary], and [NSDictionary] do not respond to rangeOfString:options: .  set breakpoint on the sentence, so you can check the name variable.

Comment: Not maybe, this is the problem.